# Is there a software package to analyse interactions in crystals?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, software-recommendations, orbitals, molecular-interactions

I have been using Quantum ESPRESSO, specifically the `pp.x` module to
study interactions via charge density plots. The process is slow as
for crystals containing complex [Zintl phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zintl_phase), I need to take planes
along with different Miller indices and study the charge density contour
plots along those planes.

**So is there a software similar to [AIM](http://aim.tkgristmill.com/index.html), which can be used to study interactions in crystals?**

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2302/24](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2302/24)

Comment: And this one too: [https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2286/24](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2286/24)

Comment: Hi @Hydrogen, were those two suggestions by Camps useful?